# Good enough deterministic PRNG based on hashes

Tags: hash, random-number-generator

Lets say I have a seed named iv which has a decent amount of entropy.

Are there any glaring issues with the following?

First 64 bytes are generated by SHA512(iv)
Next 64 bytes are generated by HMAC_SHA512(iv, Previous64Bytes)
and so on...

Obviously if I needed "perfect" security I could use something like HMAC-DRBG (NIST SP 800-90), but I need something that's good enough, easy to implement and I do not care if a supercomputer breaks it in 10 years.

Edit - More info:

- This will not be used to generate more than 500 bytes of data per run
- The implementation will be out in the open (javascript)
- Speed of the algorithm doesn't matter

Comment: Well, you're just using a homebrew pseudo-random generator. I would be very hesitant to use such a thing for cryptographic purposes; just because it "looks" random doesn't mean it is, it may be possible to predict future output based on past output, etc., etc. Not knowing your application requirements or computing constraints I couldn't recommend anything different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A deterministic PRNG is pretty much the same thing as a stream cipher. So you could go with AES-CTR or AES-OFB where available. They're standard, and are much faster than all these HMAC-SHA-512 based constructions.

But if you really want to use a hash, then I'd go with the similar [HKDF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-krawczyk-hkdf-01) construction:

Extraction Step:

```
PRK = HMAC-SHA512("", seed)
```

Expansion step:

```
T(0) = empty string (zero length)
T(1) = HMAC-Hash(PRK, T(0) | info | 0x01)
T(2) = HMAC-Hash(PRK, T(1) | info | 0x02)
T(3) = HMAC-Hash(PRK, T(2) | info | 0x03)
```

Where `info` is some string describing the purpose of your output(can be empty if you don't use a single PRK for more than one purpose), and you output `T(0) | T(1) | T(2) | ...`

The standard HKDF only uses a single byte, but if you need longer output, you could use a larger counter, such as a four byte integer.

---

With your construction, using plain SHA-512 for the first step, and HMAC-SHA-512 for the other steps is problematic. In particular if the seed is longer than 128 bytes it becomes totally insecure. Use HMAC for all steps.

If you use HMAC for every step, your construction essentially becomes OFB mode, except that you use a keyed hash instead of a block cipher.

Comment: Added some information

Comment: "In particular if the seed is longer than 128 bytes it becomes totally insecure" why ?

Comment: @Alexandre: According to the HMAC specification, if the given key is longer than the input block size of the hash, it is first reduced by hashing it with the plain hash. The input block size of SHA-512 is 128 bytes, so if the key $K$ is longer than that, $\text{HMAC-SHA512}(K,X)=\text{HMAC-SHA512}(\text{SHA512}(K),X)$, and thus the first 64 bytes of tonyk's construction will directly leak the effective MAC key.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Why shows why you should *never* roll your own crypto algorithm.

Comment: Good point, I forgot about the key reduction step

Comment: @DavidSchwartz IMO this mainly demonstrates why you should use a key only in a single way. This failure is similar to combining CBC encryption with CBC MAC using the same key.